# How to get comma seperated values in Dynamic Query SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I try this and it gives the error  "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations."
I want to get Comma seperated values in this dynamic query.
Say it should gimme Black Toy1,toy2,toy3,toy4

```
SELECT  @SQLQuery= '                          
  SELECT                      
          , Colors
          , (STUFF((SELECT ','+ st.Name  
    FROM Toys st 
          WHERE st.ToyID= Test.ColorID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS ToyName 

 FROM (
```

Comment: are you missing some part of your query after FROM (...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SQLQuery= '                          
declare @t table(Name nvarchar(20))
insert into @t values(''Peter''), (''Mike'')


SELECT STUFF((SELECT '','' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Name)
    FROM @t
    FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)''), 1, 1, '''')'

EXEC ( @SQLQuery )
```

Output:

```
Peter,Mike
```